# Microsoft.graph.teams:Failed to process content in attachment

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to send a message with Microsoft.graph.teams but return this error :Failed to process content in attachment.

```
var file3 = ImageToBase64(model.URL);
var chatMessage = new ChatMessage

Body = new ItemBody
{
    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
    Content = model.Content
},

    Attachments = new List<ChatMessageAttachment>()
        {
            new ChatMessageAttachment
            {
                Id="123",
                ContentType = " image/png",
                Content = file3,
                Name = "Spread_Anywhere.png"

            }
        }
};
    await _client.Teams[model.GroupId].Channels[model.ChannelId].Messages
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

Comment: To send a message to  Microsoft.graph.teams you need to provide an auth provider. Could you please check these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)? Try if that helps.